# IE8 Unresponsive script error popup on Elements reset

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer-8, reset

I have a js code which resets the value of elements on jsp by type on ajax response. Code runs a for loop for all elements; gets all elements by name for nearly 800-900 elements. IE 8 gives annoying popup message for unresponsive script. I have been through lot of articles regarding it but none helped so far or I couldnt implement to fix an issue.

Below is the code which is causing pop up.

```
function clearField(ele,eleType)
        {
            if(eleType=="checkbox")
            {
                        ele.prop('checked', false);
            }
            else if(eleType=="text")
            {
                        ele.val("");
                        ele.removeAttr('disabled');
                        ele.removeAttr('readonly');
            }
            else if(eleType=="radio")
            {
                if(ele.is(':checked'))
                { 
                    ele.prop('checked', false);
                }
            }
            else if(eleType=="multiple")
            {
                        if(ele.data('echMultiselect')!==undefined)
                        {
                        ele.multiselect("uncheckAll");
                        ele.multiselect("refresh");
                        }
            }
            else if(eleType=="hidden")
            {
                        ele.val("");
            }
            else
            {
                        ele.val("Select");
                        ele.removeAttr('disabled');
                        ele.removeAttr('readonly');}
        }
```

Above function gets called in for loop iteration. ele is fetched as below and passed to a function.

```
          var ele = $("input[name='"+ elementName+"']");
```

Kindly suggest if any improvement can be done or any other approach can be used to implement the same.

Answer (score 0):

The unresponsive script popup is caused by a long-running function. This blocks javascript's single threaded event loop and renders the page unresponsive until the function exits. If you run the clear asynchronously, the event loop won't get blocked. For example, you can replace clearField(ele,eleType) with setImmediate(clearField.bind(null,ele,eleType)). This is a quick hack to free up the event loop and prevent the popup from appearing, but does not address the performance issues underneath.

DOM access is an expensive operation and accessing hundreds of elements should be avoided, if possible. If your use case is to always reset all the fields to a default stage, I'd suggest having a looooong HTML string of all your elements and just calling $(parent).html(htmlString) to set the elements. This way you only need one DOM access and the effect is instantanious.

http://api.jquery.com/html/

Comment: setImmediate is not supported in IE8. To use .html() do i have to create html string of all elements? Its not feasible in this case. Is there anything that you could suggest to clear fields when we have element name on jsp and its in dynamic in nature; list keeps on changing (handled). Another reason for not using html()

Comment: For an easy fix, you could replace setImmediate with setTimeout(func, 0).  Trying to fix the DOM performance issues of this kind of problem with vanilla javascript is imo not worth your while. It's a common, well known, problem, and doing so would be reinventing the wheel. If you wish to implement the "one-time-modification" I'd suggest looking into something like virtual dom module or parts of the react framework.

https://github.com/Matt-Esch/virtual-dom
https://facebook.github.io/react/

Comment: I fixed it with setTimeout this morning but setTimeout execution for 800-1000 elements takes longer time even though it fixed the popup issue. Changing some back end logic to return elements in asc order on first tab open on screen. Im not well aware of vanillaJS. After some research I come to an article where it mentions that using vanillaJS on legacy browsers (im working on IE8) is not an good idea. I will do some research on virtual DOM; need to evaluate implementation time to make changes on existing jsps. Thank you for taking time out on this.